# Draw inside ListView item

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, adapter

I'm attempting to create a ListView where I can draw some basic shapes into each item in the ListView. I've found many examples using Views/Layouts within a ListView to add an image etc, but am unsure how I would draw into each one using a Canvas or similar. Furthermore these examples seem to all work in slightly different ways, so I was wondering what the best strategy is.

At the moment I just have a Main class which populates the ListView with basic text.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    String[] list = {"One","Two","Three"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    }
}
```

Now I gather I'll need change the Adapter bit here, and also write another class which possibly extends View, which I can draw to, then add this as an item in the ListView?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to subclass your ListView to a custom implementation.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomRowData> {

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      CustomRowData currentRow = getItem(position);
      View customRowView = .... // such as CustomRowView below.
      ...
      ...
      return customRowView;
  }
}
```

You can change the view for each row in the `ListView` by replacing the `...` with the appropriate `View` code.

For example, you can use `SurfaceView` to draw on it.

```
class CustomRowView extends SurfaceView {
  ...
  ...
  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Use |canvas| to draw on..
  }
}
```

The above code isn't tested, but hopefully will drive you to the right direction. Make sure you optimize your drawing such as use caching when available, preprocess, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've attempted to use this technique but I'm not quite there; I'm getting a Force Close at the moment when I run it. I figure it'll be easiest to post my complete code as a new question instead of completely editing this one.